# Mixin and interface implementation

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, mixins

According to http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/C%20%20_Mixins_-_Reuse_through_inheritance_is_good

> But hang on a minute, none of this helps us plug into our Task
>   Manager framework as the classes do not implement the ITask interface.
>   This is where one final Mixin helps - a Mixin which introduces the
>   ITask interface into the inheritance hierarchy, acting as an adapter
>   between some type T and the ITask interface:
>
> ```
> template< class T >
> class TaskAdapter : public ITask, public T
> {
> public:
>     virtual void Execute()
>     {
>         T::Execute();
>     }
>
>     virtual std::string GetName()
>     {
>         return T::GetName();
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> Using the TaskAdapter is simple - it's just another link in the chain
>   of mixins.
>
> ```
> // typedef for our final class, inlcuding the TaskAdapter<> mixin
> typedef public TaskAdapter< 
>                     LoggingTask< 
>                         TimingTask< 
>                             MyTask > > > task;
>
> // instance of our task - note that we are not forced into any heap allocations!
> task t;
>
> // implicit conversion to ITask* thanks to the TaskAdapter<>
> ITask* it = &t;
> it->Execute();
> ```

Why is `TaskAdapter` needed, when `ITask` is implemented by `MyTask`? Also if `ITask` is not abstract, it may lead to diamond problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a **very** cool and interesting article.

In the final Mixin example, the `MyTask` class is **not** derived from `ITask`.  Which means it can't be cast to an `ITask` pointer which is being done at the very end.

In that example, I believe you could derive `MyTask` from `ITask`.  But I think the author wanted to illustrate that you can even decouple the `MyTask` class by using the `TaskAdapter`.

Comment: ah, I missed that `MyTask` was not derived from `ITask`. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! I wrote that article and stumbled across this post accidentally.  Your comments are spot on - I wanted to demonstrate that run-time polymorphism was an opt-in concept and that you can add it when needed with a reusable mixin.

Mixins are awesome.