# Generic C++ function wrapping

Tags: c++, templates, generics, variadic-templates, typelist

I am tying to write a simple generic smart pointer template that allows a programmer to apply an arbitrary number of wraps before and after calling some function FUNC()
e.g. If a requirement was to start timer, lock, log_start,  FUNC(), log_end, unlock , stop timer

Then I would like to be able to write something simple where the programmer supplied 3 types and a function to a template and let the compiler do the rest.
I get the feeling it can be done using variadic templates in a manner similar to how typelists worked combined with overloading operator ->

i.e.

```
class timer {}; // ctor start timer, dtor stop timer
class locker{}; // ctor lock, dtor unlock
class logger{}; // ctor lock, dtor unlock
```

Then some code such as

```
template <typename ...base_class_list> 
class aggregate : public base_class_list... {};
using pre_conditions = aggregate<logger, locker, trans>;

class gadget 
{
    auto do_something() -> void;
}; // gadget
```

Finally (the part I would like to write but don’t know how to glue it together

```
SMART_PTR<pre_conditions, gadget> g;
g->do_something();
```

I can get it working easily enough using the approach described by Bjarne Stroustrup in “Wrapping C++ Member Function Calls”, but was wondering if there was a more generic and elegant solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: This question references a very good example of Mixins that I believe is related to what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193264/mixin-and-interface-implementation/34193545#34193545

Comment: I think you're into [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#cite_note-22), for which several framework and toolsets were developed around the year 2000 and later. E.g. look up [AspectC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectC%2B%2B) (I've not used it, I just found it by googling). As far as I know the idea originated at ParkPlace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to wrapping only all `operator()`:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct magic
{
    T obj;

    template <typename ... Us>
    decltype(auto) operator ()(Us...args)
    {
        ordered_tuple<Ts...> t; // tuple doesn't guaranty order
        obj(std::forward<Us>(args)...);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7ca7fe1f293617f)

To wrap `operator ->`, it is more tricky:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
class wrapper
{
    ordered_tuple<Ts...> t; // tuple doesn't guaranty order
    T* obj;
public:
    wrapper(T* obj) : obj(obj) {}

    T* operator ->()
    {
        return obj;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
class magic
{
    T obj;
public:
    wrapper<T, Ts...> operator ->()
    {
        return {&obj};
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3d71dc2f56a77de)

Handling `const` and non-default constructor should also be done. (and finding better name).

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And its now written up on the blog https://patmckblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/14/a-hidden-gem-overloading-operator/

Comment: @PMcK: I would add comment about the difference between `std::tuple` and your class `aggregate` (which might be not a aggregate btw) (that is why I called it `ordered_tuple`).